# Latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA) Algorithm not printing results in Spark Scala 1.4.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, machine-learning, rdd

I am trying to apply the LDA Algorithm in a dataset of several columns (>50) and 50,000 rows. The columns represent the attributes of different users and the rows represent the users. 
Below is an example of the raw data:

```
is_single   is_married  is_parent   watches_movie ...........
0               1          1            1
0               1          1            0
1               1          1            0
0               1          1            0
0               1          1            0
```

The corpus obtained after pre-processing is a RDD[Long, Vector].
The format that is fed in the LDA is in the format :

```
(0,[0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0....
(1,[0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0....
(2,[1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0....
.......
```

The code that I have used for the LDA is as follows :

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LDA
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

// Load and parse the data
val data = sc.textFile("data/sample_lda_data.txt")
val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.trim.split(' ').map(_.toDouble)))
// Index documents with unique IDs
val corpus = parsedData.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).cache()

// Cluster the documents into three topics using LDA
val ldaModel = new LDA().setK(3).run(corpus)

// Output topics. Each is a distribution over words (matching word count vectors)
println("Learned topics (as distributions over vocab of " + ldaModel.vocabSize + " words):")
val topics = ldaModel.topicsMatrix
for (topic <- Range(0, 3)) {
  print("Topic " + topic + ":")
  for (word <- Range(0, ldaModel.vocabSize)) { print(" " + topics(word, topic)); }
  println()
}
```

The current code is getting stuck on the first println which is the first line in the code mentioned below :

```
"println("Learned topics (as distributions over vocab of " + ldaModel.vocabSize + " words):")
val topics = ldaModel.topicsMatrix
for (topic <- Range(0, 3)) {
  print("Topic " + topic + ":")
  for (word <- Range(0, ldaModel.vocabSize)) { print(" " + topics(word, topic)); }
  println()
}"
```

It does not print any results and exits the terminal. 
Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: When you say 'The Data after pre-processing', you mean the content of the corpus variable?

Comment: You also write it is stuck on a line, but you actually pasted a block. Does it print the first println? If so does it print a vocabSize?

Comment: Hello, yes it means the corpus. And regarding the first line, it does not print the first println. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: The code looks good (I used the same code here from this sample and it works fine), but I had some issues with lda too and don't remember exactly what I did to solve. Maybe try increasing the memory when launching spark? ex. when submitting: --driver-memory 8g

Comment: It still does not work. It doesn't respond and it terminates itself after 3-4 hours, even though I am working only on 100 rows and 30 columns. I do not know why it would be such a hindrance.